# Drawing on tkinter canvas from command line

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I read some tutorial (basic) on tkinter and learned how to create a mainloop and add gui elements to that. Also learned how to bind actions to button widgets.

Now I would like to do this:

1. launch the tkinter canvas
2. be able to read command from the console and update the canvas after those commands.

example:
I write command with arguments on the console and some graphics elements is being added to the canvas (and canvas is updated after).

Is something possible, maybe threding related?
Can you point me in one direction which you think is the most reasonable to follow?

Comment: SO is not a free-code service. Please show us what you've done so far to solve the problem yourself, and provide us with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yeah i know. In fact I don't want code back. I just want to know if it is possible to accept input from the console (not reading events) and have the tkinter window updating afterwards. The problem is that I see a lot of examples with tkinter used as input interface, while I want to have the console operating as interface and the tkinter window showing only results without interaction. If it is something related to threading I will look more into that but I need a place to start.

Comment: You _can_ do this, and it doesn't even need threading, but I guess it's a bit clunky without threading. I'll post a brief demo shortly. OTOH, it's not a great experience for the user, having to alternate between the Tkinter GUI and a console window. I guess it's not too bad if you force the GUI to always be above the console window.

Comment: I ve added your example modified below, thanks!

Comment: Does the input _have_ to come from the console? Why not provide a GUI window?

Comment: Not it doesn't. I started with this idea because I wanted to use tkinter only as a canvas and nothing else. I changed my idea after some answers.

Comment: The main issue issue is that `input` (2.x `raw_input`) blocks the process until the user hits return.  I have used it, alone with print, during development and testing when I either did not care about freezing the gui or actually wanted it.  The other issue, already noted, is input focus.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple demo of grabbing user input from the console via the standard `input` function. This technique is a little clunky, since we have to explicitly tell Tkinter to fetch the input string by clicking on a Button (or some other GUI event), but that might not be a big deal for your application.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
stuff = tk.StringVar()
display = tk.Label(root, textvariable=stuff)
display.pack()

def get_input():
    s = input("CMD: ")
    stuff.set(s)

tk.Button(root, text="Get input", command=get_input).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When you click on the `"Get input"` Button, the "CMD: " prompt will be printed in the console window. Once the input is entered, the string is copied to the Label. Bad Things™ will happen if you click the button again before the input line is entered. :)

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this:

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

root = Tk()
width = 800
height = 600

def key(event):
    s = raw_input("CMD: ")

    if s == 'quit':
        root.destroy()

    if s == 'l':
        x1 = random.randint(0,width)
        x2 = random.randint(0,width)
        y1 = random.randint(0,height)
        y2 = random.randint(0,height)
        frame.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2)
        frame.focus_force()



frame = Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.pack()
frame.focus_set()

root.mainloop()
```

In this way it is a bit complicated because before entering something on the console I have to get the focus back clicking on its window. Maybe it would be nicer to read command from Tkinter directly and then opening dialogs for setting up command parameters.

Comment: Yes, getting the command from an Entry widget is simpler, both for the user, and for the programmer. OTOH, the console window has some nice features: if you `import readline` you get command line editing and history (if your platform supports readline).

Comment: Maybe is there any kind of command to put back focus to the console window after reading the key event?